# Problema com Infinite Scrolling no React

Tags: react

Estou tentando fazer um "Infinite Scrolling [(usei esse plugin do RealScout)](https://github.com/RealScout/redux-infinite-scroll)", mas mesmo sem chegar ao final da página, ele faz sempre novas requisições, sem parar. Olha na imagem:
[image: Exemplo]

Segue meu código:

**frases.jsx**

```
import InfiniteScroll from 'redux-infinite-scroll'
import { loadMore } from './frasesActions'


class Frases extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        this.props.loadMore()
    }

    renderRows() {
        const listFrases = this.props.listFrases || []
        return listFrases.map((item, index) => (
            <Grid styleCss='frase' cols='12 12 12' key={item.id}>
                . . .
            </Grid>
        ))
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Container>
                <Row>
                    <Grid cols='12 12 6' offsets='0 0 3' id='content'>
                        <Row id='frases'>
                            <InfiniteScroll
                                loadMore={this.props.loadMore}>
                                {this.renderRows()}
                            </InfiniteScroll>
                        </Row>
                    </Grid>
                </Row>
            </Container>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({ listFrases: state.frases.listFrases, user: state.auth.user })
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => bindActionCreators({ loadMore }, dispatch)
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Frases)
```

**frasesActions.js**

```
import axios from 'axios'
import consts from '../consts'

export function getFrases(start, limit) {
    const request = axios.get(`${consts.OAPI_URL}/frases/${start}/${limit}`, axios.defaults)
    return request
}

export function loadMore() {
    console.log("chamou")
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
        let state = getState()
        let list = state.frases.listFrases;
        let tmpList;
        let pageNum = 0;
        let itemCount = 15;

        if (list.length == 0) {
            pageNum = 0
        } else {
            pageNum = list.length / itemCount + 1
        }

        getFrases(pageNum, itemCount).then(function (obj) {
            tmpList = list.concat(obj.data.frases)
            dispatch({
                type: 'FRASES_CARREGADO',
                payload: {data: {
                    frases: tmpList,
                    validToken: state.auth.validToken
                }}
            })
        })
    }
}
```

**frasesReducer.js**

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {
    listFrases: []
}

export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'FRASES_CARREGADO':
            return { ...state,
                listFrases: action.payload.data.frases
            }
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```